# define a closure and execute it later on, swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift2, closures, type-alias

I am defining a block which takes 2 `String` and return nothing

```
var editingAssignmentBlock : ((String, String) -> Void)?
```

And I successfully execute block by doing this

```
 guard let block = self.editingAssignmentBlock else
   {
        return
   }
   block("This is a new shift", "This is a new type")
   }
```

Alternative, If I define a block using `typealias` like following

```
typealias editingAssignmentBlock = ((String, String) -> Void)?
```

If I am using the same way to execute a block like I did and I am getting an error like below

```
initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'editingAssignmentBlock.Type'(aka 'Optional<(String,String) -> ()>.Type')
```

Can anyone know what I am doing wrong when using `typealias` to define a block.

Comment: Are both the `var` and the `typealias` using the same name?

Comment: yup they are both same name. but i dont think it matters because I am using either way to define my block

Comment: It definitely matters. The compiler won't know if `editingAssignmentBlock` is a variable or a type. Something as simple as making the `typealias` start with a capital letter (like all types already do) may solve your problem.

Comment: Please show your real code. You've got a confusion between `editingAssignmentBlock` and `editAssignmentBlock`, so that it is impossible to guess what your code is. Show it.

Comment: my bad, it should be `editingAssignmentBlock ` in the error. I made a mistake when i typed out the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no problem here. You didn't show your real code, so who knows what's wrong with it? But I did this, and it compiles just fine:

```
typealias MyEditingAssignmentBlock = ((String, String) -> Void)?
var editingAssignmentBlock : MyEditingAssignmentBlock
func test() {
    guard let block = self.editingAssignmentBlock else {return}
    block("hey", "ho")
}
```

**EDIT** I *think* the problem is that you don't understand what a type alias is. It merely gives a name to a *type*. It defines a *synonym*. It doesn't do anything else for you. If you want a *variable* `editingAssignmentBlock`, you still need to declare it as a variable (as in my code).

In other words, think of a type alias as a form of text substitution. When you say

```
typealias MyEditingAssignmentBlock = ((String, String) -> Void)?
```

you are saying: "Whenever I write `MyEditingAssignmentBlock`, substitute `((String, String) -> Void)?`". So when I say:

```
typealias MyEditingAssignmentBlock = ((String, String) -> Void)?
var editingAssignmentBlock : MyEditingAssignmentBlock
```

...that is *the same* as performing that substitution and saying:

```
var editingAssignmentBlock : ((String, String) -> Void)?
```

But the type alias *itself* does not declare the `var` for you, by some kind of magic voodoo. The `var` declaration is still just a `var` declaration and you still need to make it explicitly if that's what you want.

Similarly, when Apple says `typealias TimeInterval = Double`, that just means "From now on, TimeInterval is another word for Double." It doesn't cause any variables to pop magically into existence.

Comment: In my case,i just did typealias,not var after that and i got the error.

Comment: After looking at your example and other examples,think i have to do both.I not really understand why.can you explain please.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand now.